# Saving value on Action or Reducer?

Tags: reactjs

Im trying to have my players to lauch dices and then save values.
Right now whats happening is that the values always reset so only 1 and 0 are generated. 
On a working example i would like to see the values being incremented like in a game, and see a player win 5-2 or 6-0 for example.

```
import { GENERATE_NUMBER } from './types';
import generateDiceNumber from '../util/DiceNumber';
export const rollDice = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    const result = [generateDiceNumber(), generateDiceNumber()];
    let playerWins = 0;
    let cpuWins = 0;
    if (result[0] > result[1]) {
      playerWins++;
    } else if (result[0] < result[1]) {
      cpuWins++;
    }
    return dispatch({
      type: GENERATE_NUMBER,
      payload: {
        result,
        playerWins,
        cpuWins
      }
    });
  };
};

//missing error validation ofc
```

This is my action

```
import { GENERATE_NUMBER, PLAYER_RESULT, CPU_RESULT } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
  number: [],
  playerWins: 0,
  cpuWins: 0
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GENERATE_NUMBER:
      return {
        ...state,
        number: action.payload.result,
        playerWins: action.payload.playerWins,
        cpuWins: action.payload.cpuWins
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I want to do this without messing up my reducer or the reducer structure. Whats the best way to do this please?

Comment: In your first code snippet, try removing the "return" keyword in front of your second dispatch call

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing the value on your store, you need to increment it. Try this:

```
return {
        ...state,
        number: action.payload.result,
        playerWins: state.playerWins + action.payload.playerWins,
        cpuWins: state.cpuWins + action.payload.cpuWins
      };
```